# Locking the version of PhantomJS that Poltergeist uses

Tags: phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

I have a Ruby on Rails app that runs feature tests using Capybara, Poltergeist and PhantomJS.

Version 2.0.0 of PhantomJS has a rather significant bug that breaks a lot of tests (https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12506) so I'd like to force the app to use a different version of PhantomJS when running the tests.

Is this possible from within Poltergeist's configuration, to raise an error or a warning if this buggy version is used, or is my best bet simply putting a note in the app's readme saying 'don't use version 2.0.0 due to this bug'?

at the moment my Capybara/Poltergeist configuration is very basic:

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
    Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, :timeout => 90)
end
```

Comment: Just do ``phantomjs -v`` and complain if it's the wrong version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @pguardiario commented, you can just do something like

```
if `phantomjs -v`.start_with? '2'
   #output whatever kind of warning you want
end
```

however the Poltergeist master branch has a fix for that particular issue so you could just try using that instead

Comment: it's not a Poltergeist issue, it's a PhantomJS one.

Comment: @sevenseacat yes, but I worked around the PantomJS issue in Poltergeist, it's in the master branch currently and will be in the next release

Comment: I see the commit that deals with that. I'm not sure how it works, but after upgrading Poltergeist to 1.8 my specs can no longer find file fields at all.

Comment: @sevenseacat Which probably means they have opacity=0 since poltergeist now checks that like the rest of the drivers -  If you do have them opacity=0 floating over a button so you can style it, then you'll need to inject css into the element using execute_script to make it visible and then set the files on it when testing - if thats not the case file an issue over on poltergesit with a reproducible test case